# Dead battery, but headlights not dim

Tags: battery, fiat

My car will not start this morning and I tried jumping starting it off a friends car with no luck. I think it is the battery as my existing one was quite old and it was freezing overnights. Also when I first attempted to start I could hear what I assume is the starter at a medium-pace, after a couple more tries of the ignition the pace has slowed and slowed with what I assume is the battery draining. Now when I turn the key there is bearly a sound

Does this still sound like a dead battery? I thought the headlights would also be dead?

Thanks

**Solution: Breakdown engineer tested battery, "60% health" - had enough amps to power lights etc but not to start engine. Was able to jump start using a Power Pack but not another car. Battery was 9 years old, replaced and all good.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cranking the engine over to start the car takes significantly more amps that the draw from your headlight bulbs.  What you describe sounds like a classic case of low battery.  As you rightly say, this is probably because the battery is old and suffering in the bitterly cold weather.

Comment: Going to purchase and swap out the battery today and hope for the best... Thanks for your reply

Comment: New battery and it starts fine!